# bluetooth socket warning

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

```
public class Bluetooth_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
BluetoothSocket socket;
String uuid = "fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66";
public OutputStream outputStream;
BluetoothAdapter mbluetoothaadapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth_activity);
    mbluetoothaadapter= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    final BluetoothController mBTController = BluetoothController.getInstance().build(Bluetooth_activity.this);

    mBTController.setBluetoothListener(new BluetoothListener() {


        @Override
        public void onActionStateChanged(int preState, int state) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActionDiscoveryStateChanged(String discoveryState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActionScanModeChanged(int preScanMode, int scanMode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBluetoothServiceStateChanged(int state) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActionDeviceFound(BluetoothDevice device, short rssi) {
            BluetoothDevice dispositivo = mbluetoothaadapter.getRemoteDevice(device.getAddress());

            try {
                device.createBond();
                socket = dispositivo.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(uuid));//create a RFCOMM (SPP) connection
                socket.connect();
                Log.i("state", "connnected");
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Connection to bluetooth device successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onReadData(BluetoothDevice device, byte[] data) {

        }
    });
    Log.i("soc",""+socket);
    mBTController.startScan();
}
}
```

**i am trying to connect to a android device using my own android app via bluetooth ,i am getting this warning(in the image) which is not allowing me to connect to any device.i searched why the warning is coming i found out it is because i am trying to open two sockets at a time so i tried to close all the opened sockets but it also gives error that there are no opened sockets .please help me to figure out this problem

thanks in advance   **

Comment: "i tried to close all the opened sockets but it also gives error that there are no opened sockets". Please provide the code for your try

Answer (score 0):

```
// This method is called back when a new device is found, it is where you get any
// information from the BluetoothDevice, you can keep this information in a list
// which shows all the BluetoothDevices that were found
mBTController.setBluetoothListener(new BluetoothListener() {

    @Override
        public void onActionDeviceFound(BluetoothDevice device, short rssi) {
        // Your problem is you are connecting every device when it is found
    }
    ....
}

// Pick up a BluetoothDevice from the list and call connectDevice(selectedDevice)

// This is where you connect to the desired BluetoothDevice
void connectDevice(BluetoothDevice myDevice)
{
    device.createBond();
    socket = dispositivo.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                UUID.fromString(uuid));//create a RFCOMM (SPP) connection
    socket.connect();
    Log.i("state", "connnected");
    outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
          "Connection to bluetooth device successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: i have tried your solution sir ,i tried to connect to a single device but it shows same error,is there any other solution.thanks for replying sir .